# Why is Pandas UDF not being parallelized?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have data from many IoT sensors. For each particular sensor, there's only  about 100 rows in the dataframe: the data is not skewed. I'm training an individual machine learning model for each sensor.

I'm using `pandas udf` successfully to train and log mlflow metrics of different models in parallel (supposedly), as taught [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/05/19/manage-and-scale-machine-learning-models-for-iot-devices.html).

Using Databricks on Azure with a single node cluster (Standard_DS3_v2 - 14GB of memory - 4 cores) I was able to finish all the training in about **23min**.

Since `pandas udf`, supposedly, does the computing in parallel for each group, I thought that I could finish the training faster by using a single node cluster with more cores, or by using a cluster with more workers. So I tried to run the same notebook with:

1. A cluster of computers: 1 master + 3 workers, all (Standard_DS3_v2 - 14GB of memory - 4 cores)
2. A single node cluster with (Standard_DS5_v2 - 56GB of memory - 16 cores)

For my surprise, the training time did not decreased: **23min** for option 1, and **26.5min** for option 2

I tried to use the [newer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#pandas-function-apis) `applyInPandas`, but the result was roughly the same.

NB: After @Chris answer, checking the Stage Detail page on the Web UI (for the cluster with 1 master + 3 workers), I see that I have only one stage responsible for the udf pandas training. It took 20 min. Acessing the details of this stage, I see it had only one task, with `{'Locality Level': 'PROCESS_LOCAL'}`, that took the whole 20min. Screenshots below.

So @Chris has identified the problem: the training is not being parallelized.

In order to understand why the `applyInPandas` (or `udf pandas`)  is not being parallelized, I put my code below (with the `applyInPandas` version). Note that my goal is only to log the trained models metrics with `mlflow`, so what the function returns is just the original df it receives.

Note also that the code is working as expected. mlflow is logging the training successfully. My only issue is why it's not being parallelized.

I have a feeling that the issue is with the `for loop`, since it differs from the [tutorial](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/05/19/manage-and-scale-machine-learning-models-for-iot-devices.html).

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
import mlflow
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error
import pmdarima as pm
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX

def train_model(df_pandas):
  '''
  Trains a model on grouped instances
  '''
  original_df = df_pandas.copy() #the original df will be returned in the end
  PA = df_pandas['Princípio_Ativo'].iloc[0]
  run_id = df_pandas['run_id'].iloc[0] # Pulls run ID to do a nested run
  
  
  observacoes_no_teste = 12
  horizonte = 1
  observacoes_total = len(df_pandas.index)
  observacoes_no_train = len(df_pandas.index) - observacoes_no_teste
  
  try:
    #train test split
    X = df_pandas[:observacoes_no_train]['Demanda']
    y = df_pandas[observacoes_no_train:]['Demanda']

    # Train the model
    model = pm.auto_arima(X, seasonal=True, m=12)

    order = model.get_params()['order']
    seasonal_order = model.get_params()['seasonal_order']


  except:
    pass
 
  # Resume the top-level training
  with mlflow.start_run(run_id=run_id, experiment_id=1333367041812290):
    # Create a nested run for the specific device
    with mlflow.start_run(run_name=str(PA), nested=True, experiment_id=1333367041812290) as run:
      
      mae_list = []
      mse_list = []
      previsoes_list = []
      teste_list = []
      predictions_list = []

    
      try:
        #the purpose of the following loop is to do backtesting: the model is trained with n observations, and the (n+1)th is predicted. n is increased by 1 on each iteration.
        for i in range(observacoes_total-observacoes_no_train-horizonte+1):
          #train test split
          X = df_pandas[:observacoes_no_train+i]['Demanda']
          y = df_pandas[observacoes_no_train+i:observacoes_no_train+i+horizonte]['Demanda']
          #train model
          model = SARIMAX(X, order=order, seasonal_order=seasonal_order)
          model = model.fit()
          #make predictions
          predictions = model.predict(start=observacoes_no_train + i, end=(observacoes_no_train + i + horizonte-1))

          predictions_list.append(predictions)

          mse = round(mean_squared_error(y, predictions),2)
          mae = round(mean_absolute_error(y, predictions),2)

          mse_list.append(mse)
          mae_list.append(mae)

        #series with predictions
        in_sample_predictions = pd.concat(predictions_list)
        in_sample_predictions.name = 'in_sample'
        #out of sample predictions
        hp = 3
        out_of_sample_predictions = model.predict(start=observacoes_total, end=(observacoes_total + hp - 1))
        out_of_sample_predictions.name = 'out_sample'
        #in sample + out of sample predictions
        df_predictions = pd.concat([df_pandas.drop('run_id',axis=1), in_sample_predictions,out_of_sample_predictions], axis=1)
        #save df with predictions to be logged as an artifact my mlflow.
        df_predictions.to_csv('df_predictions.csv')

        #mlflow logging
        mlflow.log_param("Princípio_Ativo", PA)
        mlflow.log_param("mae_list", str(mae_list))
        mlflow.log_param("mse_list", str(mse_list))
        mlflow.log_param("status_sucesso", 'sim')
        mlflow.log_artifact('df_predictions.csv')
      except:
        mlflow.log_param("status_falha", 'sim')

  return original_df.drop('run_id', axis=1)
```

```
with mlflow.start_run(run_name="SARIMA", experiment_id=1333367041812290) as run:
  run_id = run.info.run_uuid

  modelDirectoriesDF = (df
    .withColumn("run_id", f.lit(run_id)) # Add run_id
    .groupby("Princípio_Ativo")
    .applyInPandas(train_model, schema=df.schema)
  )
  
combinedDF = (df
  .join(modelDirectoriesDF, on="Princípio_Ativo", how="left")
)

display(combinedDF)
```

Screenshots from the Spark UI:
[image: Picture1]
[image: picture2]
[image: picture3]

Comment: A stage with only one task is not parallelised. Posting code snippet and Web UI screenshot would help others to diagnose.

Comment: @Chris just did it.

Comment: @marcus were you able to figure out a solution to this, I have a dataset with 6 million rows that I want to run multiple models on in parallel but when I use the example in the docs it seems like it is running only on one core.

I tried repartioning but it still does not use all the cores available.

Comment: Hey @marcus did you figured this out ? I am facing the same issue here. I have already tried to force a repartition, and my data is not small, but seems that it's not working properly.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. Per Chris' suggestion, I explicitly called `repartition(100)` on the dataframe before applying the pandas udf. Now, the stage has multiple tasks. But I would like know how this happens?

Comment: I think I know the reason. My dataframe is not small. However, my data is stored in s3 as a **single** large csv file. When I load the data into a dataframe, it is loaded as a single partition.

Comment: @FissehaBerhane no, I droped the issue

Answer (score 6):

Correct. A stage with only one task is not parallelised. This would explain why the runtime is not decreased by adding more cores or nodes in the cluster.

Your input dataset is small (69KB), so unless you explicitly `repartition`, Spark will write it to a single partition if the dataframe partition size is left as the default 128MB (dictated by `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` parameter). As such, it will be assigned to a single task.

Repartitioning the input by the device column should provide the parallel training you are looking for.

Comment: Checking the Stage Detail page on the Web UI (for the cluster with 1 master + 3 workers), I see that I have only one stage responsible for the udf pandas training. It took 20 min. Acessing the details of this stage, I see it had only one task, with `{'Locality Level': 'PROCESS_LOCAL'}`, that took the whole 20min. Does that mean that the pandas udf training was not parallelized?

Comment: the data is not skewed. It's a bunch of time series with 100 rows each.

Comment: Correct. A stage with only one task is not parallelised.

Comment: just wanted to stress out that this happens even when the input dataset is not that small (ie < `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes`, defaulting to 128MB) as you stated indeed

Comment: @Chris 1000 thanks for the crystal clear explanation. Saved my night.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can improve the parallelization by doing a `sort()` on `combinedDF`, before you execute the last display command. Something like:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
display(combinedDF.sort(F.col("Princípio_Ativo").asc()))
```

The code snippet above will prevent the `display` function from speculating in only evaluating some of the rows in `combinedDF`.
The idea is that by sorting the rows before the `display`, spark must evaluate them all to know the order of the rows for the `display` function. Hence, everything is scheduled for parallel execution.
Doing the `display` without sorting first, spark employs some kind of stage-wise exponential increase in the number of scheduled tasks, until enough rows are evaluated for executing `display`.