# Pandas UDF for time series clustering not being parallelized

Tags: pyspark, parallel-processing

I have time series data per category and I want to cluster them. To get the optimal number of clusters, I have to calculate the sum of squared distances of each data point from its centroid. Since this takes time, I want to parallelized it using Pandas UDF using the number of clusters **K**. However, it is not being parallelized. The data has more than 200k categories. It is not skewed and also I tested with repartitioning it though it did not make any change. I checked the Spark UI and it shows one stage with only task running forever. I have used Pandas UDF for parallelization multiple times before and it was working fine. I am not sure what is happening now. Can the issue be with the `TimeSeriesKMeans` function? I would appreciate any suggestions. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67343172/why-is-pandas-udf-not-being-parallelized) repartition has been suggested. However, in my case, (1) the data size is not small (2) the default number of partitions is more than 30 but still I increased it using repartition, but did not bring any improvement. As shown in the screenshot below, it is using only 2 worker nodes out of a maximum of 45.[image]

```
# Read data
stream = spark.read.format('delta').load('/mnt/datadrop-test/fw_fish/stream_bronze/clustering/cvr_cpa_clicks_4hourly_smoothed')

# Create an array per category
stream_array = stream.groupBy(['advertiser_id', 'campaign_name', 'keyword_text', 'keyword_id'])\
                     .agg(F.collect_list('cvr_cpa_clicks').alias('cvr_cpa_clicks'))

# create a dataframe with the number of clusters to try
# these are the possible values of K 
n_clusters = spark.range(5, 500, 5).withColumnRenamed("id","n_cluster")

# cross join them
cross_joined1 = stream_array.crossJoin(F.broadcast(n_clusters)).repartition('n_cluster')


def get_sum_of_squared_distances(df):
    k = df.n_cluster.values[0]
    df_array = df.cvr_cpa_clicks.values 
    nrows = df_array.shape[0]
    df_array = np.concatenate(df_array).reshape(nrows, -1)
    km = TimeSeriesKMeans(n_clusters = k,
                      max_iter = 500,
                      n_init = 50,
                      metric = "euclidean",
                      n_jobs = -1,
                      verbose = False,
                      max_iter_barycenter = 500,
                      random_state = 0,
                      init = 'k-means++')

    km = km.fit(df_array)
    result_df = pd.DataFrame({'n_clusters': [k], 'sum_of_squared_distances': [km.inertia_]})
    return result_df
   
   # Get the sum of squared distances for each k(number of clusters)
   sum_of_squared_distances = cross_joined1.groupBy('n_cluster').applyInPandas(get_sum_of_squared_distances, schema = "n_clusters long, sum_of_squared_distances double")

display(sum_of_squared_distances)
```